# Undertanding the mongo db insertOne() write concern parameter in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback

Everyting works fine. Nothing's broken, but there's something that's annoying me...I'm having difficulty in understanding the Mongodb insertOne() method's `<write concern>` parameter in the context of node.js.

My difficulty is that my course (Coursera - Full stack web development) material demonstrates the insertOne() as

```
collection.insertOne(
    {name: "Uthapizza", description: "test"},//a document    
    function(err,result){...};);// a callback function??
```

but the doco says

```
db.collection.insertOne(
   <document>,
   {
      writeConcern: <document>//which is a document and not a callback function
   }
)
```

As you can see, my course material passes a callback function, not a document. Am I misunderstanding the doco?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong documentation. You are looking at the "shell  methods" which are not async. The documentation for the [nodejs driver is here instead.](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne). Write concern is part of the "options" block in both methods. And the "shell" does not have callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong doco. Thanx to [Neil Lunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313887/neil-lunn) who posted [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107087/undertanding-the-mongo-db-insertone-write-concern-parameter-in-node-js/46107727#comment79177128_46107087):

> You are looking at the wrong documentation. You are looking at the "shell methods" which are not async. The documentation for the [nodejs driver is here instead](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne).. Write concern is part of the "options" block in both methods. And the "shell" does not have callbacks.